# What is the best approach to continuously poll MongoDB streams and recover from failures in a Python background task?

Tags: python, polling

so I have a background task which is to keep on listing to mongodb streams and do some processing. this task never ends and as long as the application runs i want this task to run, it this fails i want to recover and keep on doing the same thing

```
def run_task():
    while True:
        try:
            mongo_client = MongoDB()
            change_stream = mongo_client._conn.test.watch()
            for change in change_stream:
                # do some work 
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            time.sleep(10)
            continue


@app.before_first_request
def init():
    thread = Thread(target=run_task)
    thread.start()
```

actually my current solution is something like this

I'm looking for a way to improve this actually. I have hosted this as a pod on kubenates cluster, is there anygood approach I can take to do something like this ?

to run a background job which is so keep on polling until I get a response is there a better and more reliable way ?

i actually dont mind to break this down to separate service if theres a better approach I can take

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with this approach.  Why do you think there is?

Comment: I feel like this could improve a little bit. see one of my biggest issues is when autoscalling, see when there's 2 pods running the data will get duplicated. also I wonder if there any good approach I can take to improve this ?

Comment: Well, another practical approach is to create a simple TCP server, and have the apps that create the mongo records instead send it directly to your server, similar to an HTTP request (or maybe even using HTTP).  That way, you know immediately when something is changed.  Taking it farther, you could even have your server to the mongo update, just to avoid duplicating effort.

Comment: I see but still that wont prevent the data duplication right ? if the server autoscale to two servers then again the issue remaiins right

Comment: If you let the TCP server be the only entity that can write to the database, then it can arbitrate between multiple requests.  Single writer is the only way to avoid duplication.